# I need start 1-100 animations at one time

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a game, and i need to make apples falling, but i have a problem. (animations are same) When i click button 1 apple falling, but when i click button again, 1 apple eraze, and fall again. How i can made that when i click on button i have fall aple, and when click again , first apple not erase.  Now i have this code

```
public void limonplus(View v){
        final ImageView floatingImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Random random = new Random();   
        TranslateAnimation  anim = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, random.nextFloat(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, random.nextFloat(),
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f);          
        anim.setDuration(1800);
        floatingImage.startAnimation(anim);           
    }
```

Comment: In your method you operate with predefined View.
Try to use new View every time when you click button, just set it programmatically.

Comment: @VortexHeatkiller Ok, thank you. Can you say me how i can make this

Answer (score 0):

How it works: 
First, you create new instance of ImageView. Then you start animation and on animation finish - you remove image from parent layout.
Here is a code for Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button;
FrameLayout fl;
ImageView view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_drop);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void limonplus(){
    view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_resource);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
    fl.addView(view);
    Random random = new Random();
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, random.nextFloat(),
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, random.nextFloat(),
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f);
    anim.setDuration(1800);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation paramAnimation) { }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation paramAnimation) { }
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation paramAnimation) {
            fl.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            fl.removeAllViews();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("myLog","Dropped");
    limonplus();
}
}
```

Here is the code for main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Drop"
        android:id="@+id/button_drop" android:layout_gravity="left|top" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope, it solve your problem :)

Comment: You should explain how your code works - and specifically try to explain why the OP's original code doesn't.

Comment: I have already explained why the original code does not work in comments. And for my code, sure, will edit now with explamation.